# AdMob ads not displaying in app after release on the App Store

Tags: admob, release, ads, banner

I have added AdMob support in my app as documented.
The ads were showing in simulator as well as on real device.
After releasing the App on the AppStore the ads are not showing.
Banner ads specificaly are not showing.
Interstitial also are not showing when requested.
But, Rewarded video is showing when requested.

Is there a delay because the app is new?
It makes no sense, though why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was automatically fixed after about 2 days of first publish.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried download your app from the play store from an android device with different Google account (different from that one that you use to Developer Console and Adsense Account?